# How to write "\r\n" string in notepad++ using regex?

Tags: regex, notepad++

Using notepad++ and its regex find and replace mode, how to replace a string by a `"\r\n"` string ? I mean, *not* the new line characters, but the STRING `\r\n`.

I tried:
Find: `(.*)`,
Replace: `"\r\n"`

But no success, it just keeps inserting new line characters with a backslash between them...

Answer (score 1):

Find:

```
(.*)
```

Replace all with:

```
\\r\\n
```

Comment: @BoltClock: I tried exactly what you suggested and this was written in my original post (with double backslashes - and I did not omit to post it here with quadruple backslashes to display it on this site correctly). But it did not work, and somebody commented on a known bug of notepad++ (comment deleted...). Actually with an update of notepad++ it seems to work now...